# Different file server load balancing issue

Tags: asp.net, webserver, fileserver

I have implemented load balancing between two server. My project is hosted on both server. All works fine.
A problem is whenever file is uploaded it will be upload one of that server. So when I reference a path for that file in  application then there may be chance that file is missing since that file is not uploaded in another server. That mean image is required on both server at a time. 

But I don't want to upload file on both server because it is total waste of storage. 
So I want if file is not found on one server then it should take from other automatically.

How can I achieve this ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create a single shared network folder where all files are uploaded. That will place all the files to a single location. You can then create a new web site called static.yourdomain.com which will serve this files. This is a kind of CDN for your static\shared files.